# Contact Form 7 in Wordpress: How to set up for people to review what they have typed before sending?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 in wordpress. The form is simply just to type viewer's email address + Phone number and click Send!

How to setup for people to review their information one more time before sending?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action hook. You should read [documentation](https://contactform7.com/2018/01/31/contact-form-7-50/)

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 
  // do something
};       
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```